# Help parsing (וַיִּשְׁבֹּת֙) in Genesis 2:2

Tags: hebrew, genesis, grammar

I'm working through the 'Graded Reader of Biblical Hebrew' by Van Pelt & Pratico. In the second exercise, Genesis 2:1-3, I parsed (וַיִּשְׁבֹּת֙) as Piel imperfect 3ms WC, however, the book indicates it is Qal.

The book doesn't go into any detail on why this is the case. I had assumed the presence of the Daghesh Forte in the second root letter was a diagnostic for Piel.

Why is this verb a Qal and is there a general rule regarding the presence of the Daghesh Forte in the 2nd root consonant for Qal verbs?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The Westminster Morphology in the BHS in Logos Bible Software also parses וַיִּשְׁבֹּת֙ as qal, imperfect with waw consecutive, 3rd person, masculine, singular.

First note the vowel point information for the imperfect from Futato, M. D. (2003). Beginning Biblical Hebrew (p. 81). Winona Lake, IN: Eisenbrauns:

[image]

Thus, the vowel points indicates qal:

[image]

The dagesh is not from the piel for this reason.  Note in the piel imperfect the yod has a sheva and the next consonant has a regular vowel.  Thus, this next consonant would be an open syllable, except on the piel the dagesh forte doubles the consonant closing the syllable with the first of the doubled letters.

On the other hand, notice the qal vowel points.  The hireq is under the yod (not the shewa).  The first letter after the yod has a shewa.  Thus, it closes the syllable.  Thus, in the case of  וַיִּשְׁבֹּת֙ the dagesh is not a dagesh forte, but a dagesh lene.  It doesn't double the consonant (that would be difficult on a closed syllable), it changes the pronunciation.

In short, the dagesh forte of a piel will not have a constant with a sheva preceding it.

Comment: Not that iregular actually..

Comment: -1. You should be explaining why the qal looks like this, rather than just point to dictionaries that list it as such. The quote from BDB is largely irrelevant, as is that from HALOT, but for Futato more context would have been helpful (and the image could have been smaller by about 5× times).

Comment: @ Keelan I explained about the dagesh and removed the references to the lexicons.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: That is a *dagesh lene*, and the vowels match those of the *qal* and not the *pi'el* in any case. The *dagesh forte* that you're using for your diagnostic must follow a vowel other than *sheva*.

For more detail, read on...

---

***Dagesh lene***

There are two types of motivations for the use of a *[dagesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagesh)* in Biblical Hebrew. (This may be review for you, but I believe it's the source of your mistake, so I'll go over it as clearly as I can!)

The first, *dagesh lene*, is purely phonological. This means that it's triggered by the sounds that surround it. Notice that this does not include being triggered by the conjugation, the *binyan*, or the meaning of nearby elements. Not including it wouldn't change the meaning, it would be wrong.

It affects only six consonants: ב‬ *beth*, ג‬ *gimel*, ד‬ *daleth*, כ‬ *kaph*, פ‬ *pe* and ת‬ *tav*. These are the consonants that had two different variants in Hebrew when pointing was invented. To a linguist, the variants make sense: they are **stops** vs. **fricatives**. For example, כ is [k] with a *dagesh* and [x] without; the difference between those two sounds is that one is sudden and the other is continuous.<sup>1</sup>

The places where these variations occur also make sense. They're "strong" or "weak" positions. In general, a weak position is after a vowel, and a strong position is after a consonant or *sheva*. A *dagesh lene* appears on a letter in the strong position.

To bring it all together, you can expect to see ב,ג,ד,כ,פ,ת with a dagesh after a consonant or *sheva* even when **it is not a clue as to the *binyan***. That's what we see in וַישְׁבֹּת.

---

***Dagesh forte***

The other type, *dagesh forte*, is due to a different cause and does give a clue as to the conjugation, *binyan*, or meaning of nearby elements (for example, it appears after the definite article). It can also affect more letters, even ones without stop/fricative variants, by lengthening them instead.<sup>2</sup>

It's not always possible to disambiguate them, but because you can expect to see *dagesh* after a consonant or *sheva*, you know not to base your parsing on it.

---

**Yeshabeth**

Okay, you might ask, then of what use is the *dagesh forte* in identifying the *pi'el* ??

The answer is that you've mistaken the vowels for this conjugation. שבת is a strong root (without guttural, geminate, or weak letters), so we can treat it normally.

Then in the prefix conjugation, the vowels for the *qal* are יִשְׁבֹּת **yishboth** whereas the vowels for the *pi'el* are יְשַׁבֵּת **yeshabeth**.

Notice the difference. In the *qal*, between the first and second radical we have a *sheva*: שְׁבּ. This means we know the ב must have a *dagesh lene* and therefore it's not a clue about the *pi'el*.

But in the *pi'el*, between the first and second radical we have the vowel *patakh*: שַׁבּ. This means the *dagesh* on that ב must be a *dagesh forte* because it couldn't be a *dagesh lene*. So it's a clue about the *pi'el*.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> In Modern Hebrew fewer distinctions of this kind are made than in Biblical Hebrew.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Some consonants "reject" the *dagesh forte*. The usual result is that the preceding vowel changes.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the building you can use the old shortcut of "he yesterday was...".

For example:
The verb יתלבשו - he yesterday התלבש so it's hitpa'el.

So for your question: he yesterday שבת so it's qal.

*as every language, so in Hebrew this " rule" not works 100% of the times - but preety close.